# SQL Query Rewrite

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am refactoring an old application that was pulling data from an Access DB and I came across a stored procedure that I am unable to get working with SQL Server. My skills with SQL aren't close to the greatest, could someone shed a little light on how I should write this. Thanks.

```
    SELECT AgencyID, ParentID  Level, 
IIf(a.Level=1,'',IIf(a.Level=2,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;','&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'))
+Agency AS AgencyName, a.Acronym
FROM T_Agency AS a
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what this procedure is supposed to do?

Comment: Looking at it, the SQL Procedure is formatting code for HTML output by prepending &nbsp;'s (non breaking spaces) to the text, thus causing it to look indented.  Bad, bad, bad.  Do that kind of logic in the front-end, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT AgencyID, 
        ParentID,
        [Level], 
        case when a.[Level] = 1 then '' 
             when a.[Level] = 2 then '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
             else '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
        end + Agency AS AgencyName, 
        a.Acronym
FROM T_Agency AS a
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
         SELECT AgencyID, ParentID  Level, 
                case Level 
                when 1 then ''
                when 2 then '&nbsp;&nbsp;nbsp;&nbsp;'
                else '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                end + Level AS AgencyName,
                a.Acronym
           FROM T_Agency AS a
```